# How can we multiply partitioned matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Im trying to perform the following product:
[image]

Question: can we just think of each block as an element and perform the multiplication like matrix multiplication?

Comment: Ocw @ MIT, course 18.06, Prof. Gilbert Strang explains various ways of matrix multiplication including block multiplication in a nice and lucid way in his introductory lectures. Would be worthwhile for you to watch.

Comment: Agree with this. Great course!